# Nexus 5 Usb Drivers Stopped Working after Automatic Update

Tags: android, usb, drivers

my Nexus 5 screen broke and I was trying to retrieve some stuff using a tool I found which allows you to screencast you phone on your PC:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2786395

The tool was working fine until one moment when the Nexus 5 drivers automatically reinstalled themselves (windows update). Now Im trying to reinstall them manually through the device manager and nothing seems to be working..

Nexus 5 appears under Portable Devices when I plug it and there is no way to manually reinstall the drivers from \usb_driver
either "Windows has determined the driver software for your device is up to date" (MPT USB Device) or "the folder doesn't contain a compatible software driver for your device" when I chose the "have disk" option.

I tried disabling automatic driver updates but windows still installs the drivers whenever I plug the nexus in... The Nexus does not appear under any device list.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.